# Select2 textbox set initial value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 input which is a textbox and I make it this way

```
<input type="text" class="selectbox" name="selectbox['.$row[0].']" />
```

I am supposed to set the initial value dynamically from mysql like this `value="'.$row[1].'"` but it doesn't work.

Here's my Jquery that sets the select2:

```
 $(".selectbox").select2({
         placeholder: "Search for a Golf Course",
         minimumInputLength: 1,
          ajax: {
                url: "functions/searchGolfCourses.php",
                quietMillis:100,
                dataType: 'json',
                params: {
                method: 'post'
                },
                data: function (term, page) {
                // Data to be sent to the server. Usually it is just the "term"
                // parameter (and page if using pagination).
                // However, since this API simply echoes back what we send,
                return { s: term /* 's' is passed to php as $_POST['s'], this will contains the user input*/
                }
          },
    results: function(data, page) {
        //data param === received response from the server. As dataType
        //is json, jQuery automatically parses the response into an object.
        return { results: data };
    }
  }
});
```

Any idea how to set the intial value of a Select2 input box? thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Default Value in tagging in select2 jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994560/how-to-set-default-value-in-tagging-in-select2-jquery)

Comment: What format does `'.$row[1].'` have when it is rendered?

Comment: I'm using a remote data source and that replaces the data initially set.

Comment: I found a solution but ended up using the x-editable select2 here http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable

Thanks anyway :)