# Multiple selected values in ESelect2 dropdown list using Yii ESelect2 Extenstion

Tags: php, yii

I am using this in form:

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
'model'=>$model,
  'attribute'=>'Employee',
  'data'=>$model->Employee,
  'options'=>array(
    'width'=>'210','placeholder'=>'All Offices',
  ),
   'htmlOptions' => array(
'multiple' => 'multiple'
),
));
```

`$model->Employee` is an array, I want this array as selected in data, when i move to update the data, like the dropdown attribute `selected="selected"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2 is smart to populate itself with predefined values. But these must be inside the model attribute. If it's multiple the `$model->Employee` should be an array:

```
 $model->Employee = array(1=>'Allen', 2=>'John'); // or similar
```

moreover the `key=>value` in here should be mapped in the same way as the Employee model data.

Yet the 'data' parameter still should contain all the data in the range.

So try this, where `Employee` should be the model containing all the data options:

### Updated

I've added tags in options as shown in [here(usage 1st example)](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994560/how-to-set-default-value-in-tagging-in-select2-jquery).

```
 $tags= array(1=>'Allen', 2=>'John');
 $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
   'model'=>$model,
   'attribute'=>'Employee',
   'data'=> Chtml::listData(Employee::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
   'options'=>array(
    'width'=>'210','placeholder'=>'All Offices',
    'tags'=>$tags, 
   ),
   'htmlOptions' => array(
   'multiple' => 'multiple'
   ),
));
```

Comment: *$model->Employee* is an array. But this array brings data in option of this drop down but dont show as selected elements.

Comment: Yet not working and *tags* element changed its shape to classic.

Comment: It just suggest the data but not showing as selected values.