# select2 multiple select default items

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2  multiple item selector:

```
var location = document.createElement('div');
location.id = 'location'

$.each(attributes.locations, function (i, obj) {
    $('#location').append($('<option>', {
        value: obj.id,
        text: obj.name
    }));;
})

$('#location').select2({
    multiple: true
});
```

I can get the selected values with:

```
$("#location").select2('data')
```

But I cannot find any way to set the default selected locations.

My most logical attempt:

```
$("#location").val(["c9e972df-6fc7-4087-a099-77da7c9ff2e4"]).trigger("change")
```

Comment: What do you mean of `default selected locations` ?

Comment: selected locations when form is loaded

Comment: Can you provide a live example? in jsfiddle or here with snippet? you can use cdn to load select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.append()`, `select2` already have a `data` option where you pass the data with this specific format:

```
{
   id: ID,
   text: TEXT,
   selected: IS_SELECTED,
   disabled: IS_DISABLED
}
```

The best thing to do is `map` the array (even if you are using an ajax request).

Example:

```
var data = $.map(data, function(element) {
  var isSelected = false;

  if(element.country === 'ARGENTINA' || element.country === 'UK')
    isSelected = true;

  return {
    id: element._id,
    text: element.country,
    selected: isSelected
  }
});

$('#select').select2({
  data: data,
  multiple: true
});
```

Check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w751ddey/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass Array of values in .val() function

> $("#location").val(["value1","value2"])

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is give an array as `val` to your `select2` element. Try this:

```
var deflocations = ["New York", "Arizona", "Denver"];

var location = document.createElement('div');
location.id = 'location'

$.each(attributes.locations, function (i, obj) {
    $('#location').append($('<option>', {
        value: obj.id,
        text: obj.name
    }));;
})

$('#location').select2({
    multiple: true
});

$("#location").val(deflocations).trigger("change");
```

You can get more information here: [Multiple Select in select2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37918749/9192223)